# Bootstrap is not working in create-react-app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

[image]
I am trying to use this nav bar while it seems classes are not working:
I did all the steps like it was described in the documentation.
I've imported it in the index.js:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Then I tried to implement nav bar with its classes but seems very ugly and not working at all.:

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top">
      <div className="container">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/">Home<span classNameName="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
            </li>

           <li classNameNameName="nav-item">
       <Link to="/signin">Sign In</Link>
      </li>
      <li classNameNameName="nav-item">
      <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
      </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

As you see in the image it was not the real nav bar that should be visible. Another point is that after generating this app there is no index.html file at all. So the only place where I import bootstrap is index.js
How can I fix this to make nav bare work correctly with bootstrap?

Comment: please note that the native bootstrap use jquery, and jquery and react doesn't work together well interms of `dom` manipulations. You can try instead [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) or [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Comment: Should I use the 3rt library with materialize css as well? Since this should be a very large project we don't want to add too many libraries.

Comment: that's the downside. I read feedbacks that yeah libraries add weight to the whole code. Regarding on materialize css, that depends on the requirements and the preference but the last time I worked with Reactstrap it is using Bootstrap 4 which you can already modify/create your own css class to use it globally using `sass` or `scss`. Back to your question, I believe the navbar it didn't work well because jquery is missing and bootstrap rely on it also for positioning.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have installed the bootstrap package in you app module, no need to give the relative path there. you can import it by just below..

index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

OR

you can import the bootstrap file in you index.css file, i.e.

index.css

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or

```
import '~node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Now you are adding a css file, so make sure you have configured a css loader in webpack configuration.

Comment: I am also trying this css file working well but bootstrap js not.so nav bar doesn't work such collapse or dropdown...

Answer (score 2):

install bootstrap npm and install react-dom if not install. command are here

```
 npm install --save react react-dom
 npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

now add css file in your_project_name->public>index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

import  bootstrap module which you required in your component e.g is below

```
import { Button,Navbar,Nav,NavItem,NavDropdown,MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

if you need a video tutorial here is link
[react-js bootstrap video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCGPPimXgJU)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate option, I'm using Original Bootstrap Framework this way.**

Add bootstrap by `npm install bootstrap`

in `App.js` imports css and js

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "bootstrap"; // <-- JS File
```